# Conditional template in a table in dart web ui

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I recently update Dart to Dart SDK version 0.7.1.0_r27025 and have not been able to get conditional templates inside tables to work. The code I have at the moment is:

```
<td template if="loaded">
    <p>Loading</p>
</td>
<td template if="!loaded">
    <div>...</div>
</td>
```

However, if I run that in dartium and inspect the DOM all I see is

```
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

and I get a RangeError in the code that was generated by build.dart.

Has something changed in how dart handles conditional templates in tables in the latest release?

Comment: Is build.dart still running for you? I just tested my Web UI samples and they still work. I tested a conditional. Are you running the files in out ?

Comment: Here's a suggestion. Delete the out directory, run build.dart, and then run the relevant file in out/. Conditionals work for me as well, so I'm not sure where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by doing

```
<td>
    <template if="!loaded">
        <p>Loading...</p>
    </template>
    <div id="my_id"></div>
</td>
```

It seems it is no longer necessary to use the template as an attribute in tables.